# makefile removes my .cpp files

Tags: c++, makefile

this is the only line I changed on the make file, which is adding the "*.cpp" to the line:

```
SRC = $(wildcard *.c *.cpp)
```

and this is the clean target of the makefile:

```
# Target: clean project.
clean: begin clean_list end

clean_list :
@echo
@echo $(MSG_CLEANING)
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).eep
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).cof
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).map
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).sym
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).lss
$(REMOVE) $(OBJ)
$(REMOVE) $(LST)
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(SRC:.c=.s)
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(SRC:.c=.d)
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/.dep/*
```

And when I run the makefile, it removes all my .cpp file. What did I do wrong?

Thanks in advance.
Jo

Here is the definition of OBJ and LST:

```
# Define all object files.
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRC:.c=.o)) $(addprefix          $(OBJDIR)/,$(ASRC:.S=.o))

# Define all listing files.
LST = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRC:.c=.lst)) $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(ASRC:.S=.lst))
```

This is the complete make file:

```
# Hey Emacs, this is a -*- makefile -*-
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WinAVR Makefile Template written by Eric B. Weddington, Jörg Wunsch, et al.
#
# Released to the Public Domain
#
# Additional material for this makefile was written by:
# Peter Fleury
# Tim Henigan
# Colin O'Flynn
# Reiner Patommel
# Markus Pfaff
# Sander Pool
# Frederik Rouleau
#
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# On command line:
#
# make all = Make software.
#
# make clean = Clean out built project files.
#
# make coff = Convert ELF to AVR COFF.
#
# make extcoff = Convert ELF to AVR Extended COFF.
#
# make program = Download the hex file to the device, using avrdude.
#                Please customize the avrdude settings below first!
#
# make debug = Start either simulavr or avarice as specified for debugging, 
#              with avr-gdb or avr-insight as the front end for debugging.
#
# make filename.s = Just compile filename.c into the assembler code only.
#
# make filename.i = Create a preprocessed source file for use in submitting
#                   bug reports to the GCC project.
#
# To rebuild project do "make clean" then "make all".
#----------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include conf.mk
# MCU name
MCU = atmega328p


# Processor frequency.
#     This will define a symbol, F_CPU, in all source code files equal to the 
#     processor frequency. You can then use this symbol in your source code to 
#     calculate timings. Do NOT tack on a 'UL' at the end, this will be done
#     automatically to create a 32-bit value in your source code.
F_CPU = 8000000

AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER = stk500v1

# com1 = serial port. Use lpt1 to connect to parallel port.
AVRDUDE_PORT = /dev/cu.wchusbserial1420    # programmer connected to serial device

# Output format. (can be srec, ihex, binary)
FORMAT = ihex


# Target file name (without extension).
TARGET = main


# List C source files here. (C dependencies are automatically generated.)

SRC = $(wildcard *.c *.cpp)

OBJDIR = Builds
# List Assembler source files here.
#     Make them always end in a capital .S.  Files ending in a lowercase .s
#     will not be considered source files but generated files (assembler
#     output from the compiler), and will be deleted upon "make clean"!
#     Even though the DOS/Win* filesystem matches both .s and .S the same,
#     it will preserve the spelling of the filenames, and gcc itself does
#     care about how the name is spelled on its command-line.
ASRC = 


# Optimization level, can be [0, 1, 2, 3, s]. 
#     0 = turn off optimization. s = optimize for size.
#     (Note: 3 is not always the best optimization level. See avr-libc FAQ.)
OPT = s


# Debugging format.
#     Native formats for AVR-GCC's -g are dwarf-2 [default] or stabs.
#     AVR Studio 4.10 requires dwarf-2.
#     AVR [Extended] COFF format requires stabs, plus an avr-objcopy run.
DEBUG = stabs


# List any extra directories to look for include files here.
#     Each directory must be seperated by a space.
#     Use forward slashes for directory separators.
#     For a directory that has spaces, enclose it in quotes.
EXTRAINCDIRS = 


# Compiler flag to set the C Standard level.
#     c89   = "ANSI" C
#     gnu89 = c89 plus GCC extensions
#     c99   = ISO C99 standard (not yet fully implemented)
#     gnu99 = c99 plus GCC extensions
CSTANDARD = -std=c++11


# Place -D or -U options here
CDEFS = -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU)UL


# Place -I options here
CINCS =



#---------------- Compiler Options ----------------
#  -g*:          generate debugging information
#  -O*:          optimization level
#  -f...:        tuning, see GCC manual and avr-libc documentation
#  -Wall...:     warning level
#  -Wa,...:      tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#    -adhlns...: create assembler listing
CFLAGS = -g$(DEBUG)
CFLAGS += $(CDEFS) $(CINCS)
CFLAGS += -O$(OPT)
CFLAGS += -funsigned-char -funsigned-bitfields -fpack-struct -fshort-enums
CFLAGS += -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
CFLAGS += -Wa,-adhlns=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(<:.c=.lst))
CFLAGS += $(patsubst %,-I%,$(EXTRAINCDIRS))
CFLAGS += $(CSTANDARD)
CFLAGS += -gstabs
CFLAGS += -gstrict-dwarf

#---------------- Assembler Options ----------------
#  -Wa,...:   tell GCC to pass this to the assembler.
#  -ahlms:    create listing
#  -gstabs:   have the assembler create line number information; note that
#             for use in COFF files, additional information about filenames
#             and function names needs to be present in the assembler source
#             files -- see avr-libc docs [FIXME: not yet described there]
#  -listing-cont-lines: Sets the maximum number of continuation lines of hex 
#       dump that will be displayed for a given single line of source input.
ASFLAGS = -Wa,-adhlns=$(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(<:.S=.lst)),-gstabs,--listing-cont-lines=100


#---------------- Library Options ----------------
# Minimalistic printf version
PRINTF_LIB_MIN = -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_min

# Floating point printf version (requires MATH_LIB = -lm below)
PRINTF_LIB_FLOAT = -Wl,-u,vfprintf -lprintf_flt

# If this is left blank, then it will use the Standard printf version.
PRINTF_LIB = 
#PRINTF_LIB = $(PRINTF_LIB_MIN)
#PRINTF_LIB = $(PRINTF_LIB_FLOAT)


# Minimalistic scanf version
SCANF_LIB_MIN = -Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_min

# Floating point + %[ scanf version (requires MATH_LIB = -lm below)
SCANF_LIB_FLOAT = -Wl,-u,vfscanf -lscanf_flt

# If this is left blank, then it will use the Standard scanf version.
SCANF_LIB = 
#SCANF_LIB = $(SCANF_LIB_MIN)
#SCANF_LIB = $(SCANF_LIB_FLOAT)


MATH_LIB = -lm



#---------------- External Memory Options ----------------

# 64 KB of external RAM, starting after internal RAM (ATmega128!),
# used for variables (.data/.bss) and heap (malloc()).
#EXTMEMOPTS = -Wl,--section-start,.data=0x801100,--defsym=__heap_end=0x80ffff

# 64 KB of external RAM, starting after internal RAM (ATmega128!),
# only used for heap (malloc()).
#EXTMEMOPTS = -Wl,--defsym=__heap_start=0x801100,--defsym=__heap_end=0x80ffff

EXTMEMOPTS =



#---------------- Linker Options ----------------
#  -Wl,...:     tell GCC to pass this to linker.
#    -Map:      create map file
#    --cref:    add cross reference to  map file
LDFLAGS = -Wl,-Map=$(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).map,--cref
LDFLAGS += $(EXTMEMOPTS)
LDFLAGS += $(PRINTF_LIB) $(SCANF_LIB) $(MATH_LIB)



#---------------- Programming Options (avrdude) ----------------

# Programming hardware: alf avr910 avrisp bascom bsd 
# dt006 pavr picoweb pony-stk200 sp12 stk200 stk500
#
# Type: avrdude -c ?
# to get a full listing.
#

AVRDUDE_WRITE_FLASH = -U flash:w:$(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
#AVRDUDE_WRITE_EEPROM = -U eeprom:w:$(TARGET).eep


# Uncomment the following if you want avrdude's erase cycle counter.
# Note that this counter needs to be initialized first using -Yn,
# see avrdude manual.
#AVRDUDE_ERASE_COUNTER = -y

# Uncomment the following if you do /not/ wish a verification to be
# performed after programming the device.
#AVRDUDE_NO_VERIFY = -V

# Increase verbosity level.  Please use this when submitting bug
# reports about avrdude. See <http://savannah.nongnu.org/projects/avrdude> 
# to submit bug reports.
#AVRDUDE_VERBOSE = -v -v

AVRDUDE_FLAGS = -p $(MCU) -P $(AVRDUDE_PORT) -c $(AVRDUDE_PROGRAMMER)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_NO_VERIFY)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_VERBOSE)
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += $(AVRDUDE_ERASE_COUNTER)

# --------------------------- EDITED BY WIJOYO UTOMO ---------------------------
# This is to modify the baud rate to 19200 when using my Arduino Nano v-3.0 as my ISP programmer
AVRDUDE_FLAGS += -C 19200

#---------------- Debugging Options ----------------

# For simulavr only - target MCU frequency.
DEBUG_MFREQ = $(F_CPU)

# Set the DEBUG_UI to either gdb or insight.
# DEBUG_UI = gdb
DEBUG_UI = insight

# Set the debugging back-end to either avarice, simulavr.
DEBUG_BACKEND = avarice
#DEBUG_BACKEND = simulavr

# GDB Init Filename.
GDBINIT_FILE = __avr_gdbinit

# When using avarice settings for the JTAG
JTAG_DEV = /dev/com1

# Debugging port used to communicate between GDB / avarice / simulavr.
DEBUG_PORT = 4242

# Debugging host used to communicate between GDB / avarice / simulavr, normally
#     just set to localhost unless doing some sort of crazy debugging when 
#     avarice is running on a different computer.
DEBUG_HOST = localhost



#============================================================================


# Define programs and commands.
SHELL = sh
CC = /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/avr-g++
OBJCOPY = /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/avr-objcopy
OBJDUMP = /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/avr-objdump
SIZE = /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/avr-size
NM = /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/avr-nm
AVRDUDE = /usr/local/CrossPack-AVR/bin/avrdude
REMOVE = rm -f
COPY = cp
WINSHELL = cmd


# Define Messages
# English
MSG_ERRORS_NONE = Errors: none
MSG_BEGIN = -------- begin --------
MSG_END = --------  end  --------
MSG_SIZE_BEFORE = Size before: 
MSG_SIZE_AFTER = Size after:
MSG_COFF = Converting to AVR COFF:
MSG_EXTENDED_COFF = Converting to AVR Extended COFF:
MSG_FLASH = Creating load file for Flash:
MSG_EEPROM = Creating load file for EEPROM:
MSG_EXTENDED_LISTING = Creating Extended Listing:
MSG_SYMBOL_TABLE = Creating Symbol Table:
MSG_LINKING = Linking:
MSG_COMPILING = Compiling:
MSG_ASSEMBLING = Assembling:
MSG_CLEANING = Cleaning project:




# Define all object files.
OBJ = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRC:.c=.o)) $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(ASRC:.S=.o))

# Define all listing files.
LST = $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SRC:.c=.lst)) $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(ASRC:.S=.lst))


# Compiler flags to generate dependency files.
GENDEPFLAGS = -MD -MP -MF $(OBJDIR)/.dep/$(@F).d


# Combine all necessary flags and optional flags.
# Add target processor to flags.
ALL_CFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CFLAGS) $(GENDEPFLAGS)
ALL_ASFLAGS = -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. -x assembler-with-cpp $(ASFLAGS)





# Default target.
all: begin gccversion sizebefore clean build program sizeafter end

build: $(OBJDIR) elf hex eep lss sym

elf: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
hex: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
eep: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).eep
lss: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).lss 
sym: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).sym

$(OBJDIR):
    @mkdir -p $@

# Eye candy.
# AVR Studio 3.x does not check make's exit code but relies on
# the following magic strings to be generated by the compile job.
begin:
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_BEGIN)

end:
    @echo $(MSG_END)
    @echo


# Display size of file.
HEXSIZE = $(SIZE) --target=$(FORMAT) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
ELFSIZE = $(SIZE) --format=avr $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf

sizebefore:
    @if test -f $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf; then echo; echo $(MSG_SIZE_BEFORE); $(ELFSIZE); \
    2>/dev/null; echo; fi

sizeafter:
    @if test -f $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf; then echo; echo $(MSG_SIZE_AFTER); $(ELFSIZE); \
    2>/dev/null; echo; fi



# Display compiler version information.
gccversion : 
    @$(CC) --version



# Program the device.  
program: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).eep
    $(AVRDUDE) $(AVRDUDE_FLAGS) $(AVRDUDE_WRITE_FLASH) $(AVRDUDE_WRITE_EEPROM)

# Generate avr-gdb config/init file which does the following:
#     define the reset signal, load the target file, connect to target, and set 
#     a breakpoint at main().
gdb-config: 
    @$(REMOVE) $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo define reset >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo SIGNAL SIGHUP >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo end >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo file $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
    @echo target remote $(DEBUG_HOST):$(DEBUG_PORT)  >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
ifeq ($(DEBUG_BACKEND),simulavr)
    @echo load  >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)
endif   
    @echo break main >> $(GDBINIT_FILE)

debug: gdb-config $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
ifeq ($(DEBUG_BACKEND), avarice)
    @echo Starting AVaRICE - Press enter when "waiting to connect" message displays.
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start avarice --jtag $(JTAG_DEV) --erase --program --file \
    $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf $(DEBUG_HOST):$(DEBUG_PORT)
    @$(WINSHELL) /c pause
else
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start simulavr --gdbserver --device $(MCU) --clock-freq \
    $(DEBUG_MFREQ) --port $(DEBUG_PORT)
endif
    @$(WINSHELL) /c start avr-$(DEBUG_UI) --command=$(GDBINIT_FILE)



# Convert ELF to COFF for use in debugging / simulating in AVR Studio or VMLAB.
COFFCONVERT=$(OBJCOPY) --debugging \
--change-section-address .data-0x800000 \
--change-section-address .bss-0x800000 \
--change-section-address .noinit-0x800000 \
--change-section-address .eeprom-0x810000 


coff: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COFF) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).cof
    $(COFFCONVERT) -O coff-avr $< $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).cof


extcoff: $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EXTENDED_COFF) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).cof
    $(COFFCONVERT) -O coff-ext-avr $< $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).cof



# Create final output files (.hex, .eep) from ELF output file.
$(OBJDIR)/%.hex: $(OBJDIR)/%.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_FLASH) $@
    $(OBJCOPY) -O $(FORMAT) -R .eeprom $< $@

$(OBJDIR)/%.eep: $(OBJDIR)/%.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EEPROM) $@
    -$(OBJCOPY) -j .eeprom --set-section-flags .eeprom=alloc,load \
    --change-section-lma .eeprom=0 -O $(FORMAT) $< $@

# Create extended listing file from ELF output file.
$(OBJDIR)/%.lss: $(OBJDIR)/%.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_EXTENDED_LISTING) $@
    $(OBJDUMP) -h -S $< > $@

# Create a symbol table from ELF output file.
$(OBJDIR)/%.sym: $(OBJDIR)/%.elf
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_SYMBOL_TABLE) $@
    $(NM) -n $< > $@



# Link: create ELF output file from object files.
.SECONDARY : $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
.PRECIOUS : $(OBJ)
$(OBJDIR)/%.elf: $(OBJ)
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_LINKING) $@
    $(CC) $(ALL_CFLAGS) $^ --output $@ $(LDFLAGS)


# Compile: create object files from C source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.c
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_COMPILING) $<
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_CFLAGS) $(abspath $<) -o $@ 


# Compile: create assembler files from C source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.s : %.c
    $(CC) -S $(ALL_CFLAGS) $< -o $@


# Assemble: create object files from assembler source files.
$(OBJDIR)/%.o : %.S
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_ASSEMBLING) $<
    $(CC) -c $(ALL_ASFLAGS) $< -o $@

# Create preprocessed source for use in sending a bug report.
$(OBJDIR)/%.i : %.c
    $(CC) -E -mmcu=$(MCU) -I. $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@ 


# Target: clean project.
clean: begin clean_list end

clean_list :
    @echo
    @echo $(MSG_CLEANING)
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).hex
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).eep
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).cof
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).elf
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).map
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).sym
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(TARGET).lss
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJ)
    $(REMOVE) $(LST)
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(SRC:.c=.s)
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(SRC:.c=.d)
    $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/.dep/*



# Include the dependency files.
-include $(shell mkdir $(OBJDIR)/.dep 2>/dev/null) $(wildcard $(OBJDIR)/.dep/*)


# Listing of phony targets.
.PHONY : all begin finish end sizebefore sizeafter gccversion \
build elf hex eep lss sym coff extcoff \
clean clean_list program debug gdb-config
```

Since I can't post image, I will explain my directory structure. There is a Builds sub directory that holds the .hex .eep .o .elf .lst of the build (when successful). My source files and header files are not in the Builds sub directory, but in the project directory which contains the Builds directory.

Comment: I dont see anything in here that looks suspicous. Can you post the whole makefile? Atleast the definitions of $(LST) and $(OBJ)

Comment: Hi, I have provided the information about the OBJ and LST. BTW, how do you paste a long text of code without indenting with 4 spaces manually?

Comment: Use the toolbar in the editor. The code brackets will indent a selected block for you.

Comment: Thanks Bart, just figure out that I have to paste the code, select it, and pressing ctrl-k to indent all the lines, and voila.

Comment: What is OBJDIR? If it's empty then you'll delete the cpp files while trying to clear .s and .d.

Comment: Alan and errr... (Mad??), I have uploaded all the makefile. Mad, you are right, if I comment out the  $(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(SRC:.c=.d), the makefile does not delete my .cpp files.

Comment: I don't understand the state of this question.  I didn't suggest commenting out that line, I suggested a way to change it to make it work properly.  Did the change do what you wanted?  If it did you should mark the response as the accepted answer.  If it didn't, please provide more information.

Comment: Yes, I understand that you did not ask me to comment out, but along the way while waiting for a reply on this forum, I tried to comment out the clean up command one by one to see which command which actually removed my cpp files. Now I am reading some more of the make manual to try to figure out and understand your suggestion. Spare with me, I am a rookie. And thanks a lot for pointing me to which direction to tackle this problem. This make utility is giving me quite a headache now. :D I will come back again with any question that I am pretty sure to come up considering my level of knowledge.

Answer (score 6):

Alan Stokes is correct, except it doesn't matter what value `OBJDIR` has, because your `clean` rule is badly written.  Consider this line in the clean rule:

```
$(REMOVE) $(OBJDIR)/$(SRC:.c=.s)
```

It's a common mistake to think that just by prefixing a variable with another variable, every *word* in the second will be prefixed by the first, but that's just not true.  That's what `addprefix` is for (or `patsubst` if you prefer).  The above line expands to this (assuming `REMOVE` is `rm -f`, `OBJDIR` is `obj`, and `SRC` is `foo.c bar.c biz.c baz.c`):

```
rm -f obj/foo.s bar.s biz.s baz.s
```

You can immediately see this is not what you wanted.

Now consider what happens when you add all the `.cpp` files, so `SRC` is now `foo.c bar.c biz.c baz.c one.cpp two.cpp three.cpp`.  The substitution `$(SRC:.c=.s)` will replace the `.c` suffixes, *BUT* it will *not* touch any words that don't match the pattern.  So, the command you run becomes:

```
rm -f obj/foo.s bar.s biz.s baz.s one.cpp two.cpp three.cpp
```

So you have two problems: the first is you should be using `addprefix` (or `patsubst`) to prefix *all* the words with the directory, and the second is you should be using the `basename` function to remove the suffix for *all* the words.  There are multiple ways to do it but something like this will work:

```
$(REMOVE) $(patsubst %,$(OBJDIR)/%.s,$(basename $(SRC)))
```

And of course, you have to do the same with your rule for `.d` files.  I strongly recommend you try it first with `make -n` before you let it rip for real.

Comment: Great answer. It turned out this basic pattern was also wrong in my definition of the OBJS, perhaps a common error, so I was defining a lot of OBJs that were slowing down my compile, and removing the OBJs was going sideways.